Handling missing values using missMDA?
I am working on an SNP dataset for fish. The SNP data has a lot of NA values due to rare alleles in each population. I want to handle the NAs using the missMDA package. However, when I run my code, I get the following error:
Error in eigen(crossprod(t(X), t(X)), symmetric = TRUE) : 
  infinite or missing values in 'x'

How do I solve this?
I tried converting the data from integer to factor, but that didn't work either. Please help me.
My initial code is:
nb <- estim_ncpPCA(data, scale=TRUE)

My data looks like this

The structure of data is data frame with integers

Hi Kath. Please make this a reproducible question by editing it to include a representative sample of data that produces the error.

What is the rationale behind converting integers into factors?

@jay.sf Hello! I just read in one of the forums here that the error could be solved by converting it into factors. However, after converting, it is still not working

You seem to have one or more columns that are entirely NA. There's no point to keep them, so remove.
> library('missMDA')
> data(orange)
> orange[, 4] <- NA_integer_  ## make entire column NA
> estim_ncpPCA(orange, scale=TRUE) 
Error in eigen(crossprod(X, X), symmetric = TRUE) : 
  infinite or missing values in 'x'
> keep <- colSums(is.na(orange)) != nrow(orange)
> orange_clean <- orange[, keep]  ## remove NA columns
> estim_ncpPCA(orange_clean, scale=TRUE) 
$ncp
[1] 2

$criterion
          0           1           2           3           4           5 
1.118814167 0.980301039 0.651926140 0.792951353 0.847692944 0.001247322 

Warning message:
In impute(X, ncp = ncp, scale = scale, method = method, ind.sup = ind.sup,  :
  Stopped after  1000  iterations

The package authors could provide a better error message.

Hello! I have done this, but still I am getting the "Error in eigen(crossprod(t(X), t(X))" error.
